# Loading all columns of CSV into Oracle table in bulk

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to load all the columns from my CSV into my Oracle table. The columns between the two match. I am trying to make the query dynamic so I would use it to load data from any CSV to any matching table, therefore, I want to avoid naming the columns names (the jobCounter column should be replaced with a wildcard (if there's any). I'm not sure if that is the right way.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\Users\Theuser\Documents\20121017.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE SRT_FACTOR_20121017
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
   jobCounter //* I want to replace this with an asterisk to include all the columns
)
```

At the moment, I'm getting the following error when using Oracle SQL Developer:

```
Error at Command Line : 217 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Line 217 is deep in the bowels of your data file. Take a look at lines about 205 - 220 in the data file and see if there's something funky there.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you **cannot** load any columns to a matching table via SQL*Loader. The fields defintion **must** be exact.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run the sqlldr script in SQL Developer. SQL Developer only understand SQL and PL/SQL for the most part.

So you've used SQL Developer to generate that script for you - you're almost there.

Now just run that script from your doc/NIX cmd/shell prompt...assuming you have an Oracle Client installed that includes the sqlldr program.

Need more help? I talk about this process [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/).

Comment: I have run it in SQL Developer to test it before I plug it in my .NET code. Are you saying that it doesn't work in SQL Developer and therefore in my code?

Comment: the code you show would only EVER work in the sqlldr program itself

Answer (score 0):

The file you provided is a control file to be used by sqlldr. It basically tells sqlldr what data and in which table (and corresponding columns) to store said data.

If you want to include the load inside your .NET project you must run an external command, which calls sqlldr with certain parameters.

Example:

```
public static void loadDataFromFile(string dbUser, string dbHost, string dbPass, string ctrlFile, string loaderLog, string loaderBad)
{
    Process prcLoader = new Process();
    prcLoader.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlldr";
    prcLoader.StartInfo.Arguments = dbUser + "@" + dbHost + "/" + dbPass + " control=" + ctrlFile + " log=" + loaderLog + " bad=" + loaderBad + " errors=9999";
    prcLoader.Start();
    prcLoader.WaitForExit();
}
```

I recommend you encrypt the database connection data such as dbUser, dbPass etc and decrypt them when calling the above method. One way to achieve this would be to just store the encrypted data in your project settings and read it from there.

The strings below are the paths to the files, where ctrlFile = the control file (the one you posted), loaderLog = output of sqlldr (contains successful loaded rows), loaderBad = output of sqlldr (contains unsuccessful rows, which could not be loaded).

```
string ctrlFile, string loaderLog, string loaderBad
```